# Changing permitted arrow directions of popover after displaying it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller

Is it possible to change the permitted arrow directions of a popover after it has been created and displayed? I know that I can allow the permitted directions to be limited to just two directions (ex. `UIPopoverArrowDirection permittedDirection = UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft | UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight`) but I want to change it between the two based on what the user is currently viewing.

Comment: Also note that the _popoverArrowDirection is not being set ever when looking at its value while debugging. Yet, the first object to create a popover will work correctly but then using a navigation controller in the popover to cycle through other popovers will not update the popovers position or arrow direction, but will update its contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change this while the popover is on screen. The only thing you can do is dismiss the popover and display it again with a different arrow direction.